# Does EPOLLONESHOT prevent multiple events on a single descriptor from being returned in a single call to epoll_wait()?

Tags: linux, network-programming, epoll

The man page on [`epoll_ctl(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_ctl.2.html) has this to say about the `EPOLLONESHOT` flag:

```
Sets the one-shot behavior for the associated file descriptor.
This means that after an event is pulled out with
epoll_wait(2) the associated file descriptor is internally
disabled and no other events will be reported by the epoll
interface.  The user must call epoll_ctl() with EPOLL_CTL_MOD
to rearm the file descriptor with a new event mask.
```

However, it isn't clear whether the event is disabled in an `epoll_wait` after being inserted into the event array or after all events have been returned.

Comment: I don't think it is worth to mention, how both the cases differ ? do you have any usecase based on this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The behavior of `EPOLLONESHOT` is such that after a successful call to `epoll_wait(2)` where the specified file descriptor was reported, no new events will be reported by `epoll_wait(2)` on the same file descriptor until you explicitly reactivate it with `epoll_ctl(2)`. You can look at it as a mechanism of temporarily disabling a file descriptor once it is returned by `epoll_wait(2)`.

It does not prevent `epoll_wait(2)` from returning more than one event in the same call for the same file descriptor - in fact, if multiple events are available at the time of the call, they are all combined into the `events` field of `struct epoll_event`, whether or not `EPOLLONESHOT` is in effect for that file descriptor.

In other words, `EPOLLONESHOT` controls under what conditions a file descriptor is *reported* in a call to `epoll_wait(2)`; it does not play a role in event aggregation and detection.

**An Example**

The code below creates a pair of connected sockets and writes to one end. `sv[1]` will be available for read and write. As you can see, adding or removing `EPOLLONESHOT` has no effect on the fact that `EPOLLIN` and `EPOLLOUT` are combined into one event.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main(void) {
    int efd = epoll_create(1);
    if (efd < 0) {
        perror("epoll_create(2) error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int sv[2];
    if (socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sv) < 0) {
        perror("socketpair(2) error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    const char str[] = "Hello, world!";
    size_t to_write = sizeof(str)-1;
    ssize_t written = write(sv[0], str, to_write);

    if (written != to_write) {
        if (written < 0) {
            perror("write(2) error");
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "short write detected: %zd/%zu\n", written, to_write);
        }
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct epoll_event epevent;
    epevent.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLOUT | EPOLLONESHOT; // Try to remove EPOLLONESHOT here
    epevent.data.fd = sv[1];

    if (epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sv[1], &epevent) < 0) {
        perror("epoll_ctl(2) error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct epoll_event events_arr[16];
    int events = epoll_wait(efd, events_arr, sizeof(events_arr)/sizeof(*events_arr), -1);
    if (events < 0) {
        perror("epoll_wait(2) error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < events; i++) {
        printf("Event %d: ", i);
        if (events_arr[i].events & EPOLLIN)
            printf("EPOLLIN ");
        if (events_arr[i].events & EPOLLOUT)
            printf("EPOLLOUT ");
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please take a look at this [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60502936/when-using-epolloneshot-do-all-events-flags-have-to-be-rearmed-after-epollin-eve